# "IF" condition in left join in "SAS" proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table `a`, which contains columns `a1` and `a2`.

I have  a table `b`, which contains columns `b1` and `b2`.

I want to `left join` `b` to `a` on `condition1` if `a2 is null` and on `condition2` if `a2 is not null`.

How can i construct this query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
proc sql;
    select . . .
    from a left join
         b
         on (a2 is null and condition1) or
            (a2 is not null and condition2);
```

This is a direct translation of your requirements.  In general, the following often has better performance because this can make better use of indexes (depending on the nature of the conditions):

```
proc sql;
    select a.*, coalesce(b1.b2, b2.b2) as b2
    from a left join
         b b1
         on (a2 is null and condition1) left join
         b b2
         on (a2 is not null and condition2);
```